# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error when using webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I was using a PHP script written using CodeIgniter. when I run it from the localhost, it works well, but when running from my web host, it shows a 500 Internal Server Error.

I read here that this might be due to a wrong code in the .htaccess file. This is my present .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Important part www seems to cause some issue with login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I know it might be a very small problem, but I'm unable to find the error.

Comment: Whats in the error log?

Comment: Do you have access to `error.log`?

Comment: its not even showing error log thats the problem .

Comment: it works well without any error in localhost but in webserver it shows the error . even not showing the error log

Comment: Just to be sure that the error is related to .htaccess, if you comment those lines your code works fine?

Comment: Enable appache re-write module